# Animating adding/removing items with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to slide-up/slide-down items in a `<UL>` as they are added and removed.

I've followed the angular docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations), and am trying to use a simple js-hook based (rather than css-hook based) solution, that uses this angular animation:

```
app.animation('.slide', function () {
    return {
        enter: function (element, done) {
          console.log('enter');
            element.slideDown(200, done);
        },
        move: function(element, done) {
            console.log('move');
            element.slideUp(200, done);
        },
        leave: function(element, done) {
            console.log('leave');
            element.slideUp(200, done);
        }
    };
});
```

But, that doesn't work on the slide up, only on the slide down. I've recreated as a plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9X0apgxKbqMBKbQmmY6Z?p=preview

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) works for hidden item and `slideUp` just opposite of it.

So before `slideDown` you have to hide first

```
element.hide().slideDown(200, done);
```

Check the updated [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/344tXH4SjdiPN150rlSI?p=preview)